# Xcode won't let to build for Device after denying Codesign to access Keychain

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain, codesign

I'm new to iOS development and today I tried to check my app on my iPhone and tried to build it for the device. So when I clicked on build, it asked to type my password to let codesign to access keychain. But after few attempts, I accidentally clicked on deny button. Then after again I tried to build my app for the device and now it says,

```
Swift sodlib tool error, task failed with exit 1 signal 0
```

And when I check that error it says,

```
unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
/usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' 'A6646CD79C82476C1C35598A10134D3171EE09CD' '--verbose' '/Users/samitha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestFoodTracker-gdcqosdrvtooqocosgttmwyzvgtg/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TestFoodTracker.app/Frameworks/libswiftContacts.dylib'
```

**What I Did**

I tried to let codesign to access "keychain Access" and checked every key under login, but in Access Control section of each key, "Allow all applications to access this item" have been selected.

I couldn't find any more ways to correct that mistake and let my app to be built for my device. Please if there anyone know how to correct this, just help me. Thanks.

Comment: Could you try removing and then adding the key to the keychain again?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I found a solution for that. If that error occurs, only you have to do is just lock the [keychain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_(software)) (click on lock in the left upper most corner). Then build again. It will ask to unlock again like first time and Let you to choose `always allow` or `allow` or `deny` in Codesign keychain access. Just type account (Mac User account) password and click on always allow. Then project will build successfully.

Comment: What do you mean click on the lock in the upper left corner? Where?

Comment: @FrankTheTank By shear dumb luck I had this unnamed window open. It's the Keychain Access window. If you search for "Keychain" on the Mac, it should be the first result. When that's open, The padlock underneath the close/min/maximize buttons is what they're talking about. A note, depending on what you have selected in the left panel section "Keychains", you can unlock more than one thing. Hope this makes sense. Because Mac NEVER makes sense....

Comment: It worked for me, i only found that since i previously changed my password from console the keychain password wasn't changed eitherso i had to use my old one; probably the OSX password management routine does some things that the passwd command does not do, keep in mind if your usual password doesn't seem to work properly

Comment: I was getting the error "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" and this fixed it.