# Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {

Tags: ios, xcode9

i have updated my mac OS with High sierra and updated my xcode from 9.2 beta to 9.3 now i'm trying to run my project in xcode but i'm getting this error,

```
error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
/usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' 'D07F0514ABB5168A2686CB2404531DC9F81CBB26' '--verbose' '/Users/hamza/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARPortalDemo-ablkjxbynnihakhdfdihocryaejd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARPortalDemo.app/Frameworks/libswiftARKit.dylib'
```

}

I have searched about the solution many of them are saying to delete the derived data.I have done that but it isn't going. How can i resolve this? Why this error comes?

Comment: It will work with clean derive data and restarting the system. There may be some configuration errors, but you may look the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932620/device-build-fails-after-upgrading-to-xcode-8?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa